# Apply new cell value without pressing Enter or moving focus

Tags: excel

Well, This is my problem
I'm making alot of cell value testing in Excel, when i enter to apply the new value, the focus left the cell to the cell under it, so i have to return to the cell the change/apply again and again.
Is there a key in the keyboard to apply changement without quitting the cell ?
Is there a sitting in excel to apply changement while editing ?

Thank You all for your help

Comment: I don't think this is about programming within the scope defined for SO. _"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com)."_

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the File, Options, Advanced, Editing options, After pressing Enter move selection option.

In VBA as,

```
Application.MoveAfterReturn = False
```